# HTTP vs HTTPS in blog link

Tags: discussion, blog

I don't know how this is possible, but I get

- the TeX SE blog for http://tex-talk.net
- and a completely different page for https://tex-talk.net:

[image]

What is happening here? How is it possible? What can be done against that?

Comment: Not all sites have a certificate. The second link shows the standard untrusted page which is what you get if there's no certificate (and also get if there's something wrong with the certificate). My guess is that only the `http` link is valid.

Comment: But it's still a completely different page on the same URL. Previously I thought that HTTP and HTTPS were just different ways to access the same page, but apparently there can be different pages on those. But why? And isn't that a problem for browsers that add `http://` or `https://` automatically?

Comment: You can't use https on a site that doesn't have the security layer enabled. (You have to pay yearly for a certificate so small sites that don't generate any income from ads etc tend not to have them.) If I try https://tex-talk.net I don't get further than the security warning page. Could you add an image of what you see when you try it?

Comment: Added the picture.

Comment: That looks like https://texfragen.de/ (which is a secure connection) but notice that it's struck out `https` so it may be a redirect to a secure link triggered by the invalid https request. (But I'm just guessing.) I think Stefan Kottwitz would be the best person to answer this question (he's the author/host of TeX Talk and, if my limited understanding of German is correct, he's author of the other page as well).

Comment: I wrote Stefan a mail with a link to this question. I guess he will have a look at this once a bit of spare time is available.

Comment: `http` and `https` use different port numbers (80 vs 443). There is absolutely nothing stopping someone from running two web servers on the same host, each accepting connections on one of those ports and serving different data. Whether that is wise, is another question; but doing it is trivial. The most common use case is to run a server on port 80 that redirects all requests to `https`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: HTTPS support installed, certificate made with "Let's Encrypt".

https://tex-talk.net

---

Thanks, I will soon get a certificate for the blog and that will fix it.

The blog wasn't https enabled yet, so it happened that it fell back to the next https enabled site on the same server, that's the german FAQ site.

I will update this answer then.

Comment: When will you get a certificate for http://texwelt.de ?